# Unable to define FileOutputStream in Android JUnit Test

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write the unit test case for generating a log file in the sdCard folder of the device. But I'm facing an error of initialisation for the `FileOutputStream`. Below mentioned the class for which I'm writing the test case.

```
@Singleton
class TracLogger @Inject constructor(
private val iTracLogInfo: ITracLogInfo,
@ApplicationContext val context: Context){
private lateinit var logFileOutputStream:FileOutputStream
private lateinit var file:File

    init {
    val logsFolder = File(logFolder)
    if (!logsFolder.exists()) logsFolder.mkdir()
    try {
        file = File(logsFolder.absolutePath + "/" + iTracLogInfo.appName + "log.txt")
        logFileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file,true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG,"writeLogToFile failed with error "+e.message)
    }
}

override val logFolder: String
    get() {
        var path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        return if(path != null) path.absolutePath + "/logs" else "/sdcard/Download/logs"
    }

override fun log(msg: String) {
    try {
        if(logFileOutputStream != null){
            logFileOutputStream.write(formatLog(msg).toByteArray())
            logFileOutputStream.flush()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Error in writing log i.e.($msg) to file "+e.message)
    }
}
}


interface ITracLogInfo {
val appName: String
val atLeastSizeLimitToUpload: Long
}
```

The test class what I'm writing is mentioned below:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class TracLoggerTest {
private lateinit var logger: TracLogger
private var iTracLogInfo: ITracLogInfo = mock()
 private val context: Context = mock()

@Before
fun setup() {
    Mockito.mockStatic(Log::class.java)
    logger = TracLogger(iTracLogInfo, context)
}

@Test
fun testLog() {
    val message = "Test message"
    logger.log(message)
    val logFile = File(logger.logFolder + "/" + iTracLogInfo.appName+"log.txt")
    val input = logFile.inputStream()
    val output = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var length: Int
    while (input.read(buffer).also { length = it } != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }
    assertEquals(
        "${
            DateFormatterUtility.formatDateTimeToString(
                Date(),
                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"
            )
        } : $message \n",
        output.toString()
    )
}
```

The error is `lateinit property logFileOutputStream has not been initialized` on the line `if(logFileOutputStream != null){`

It would be great if you could please highlight the problem and guide to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to create a file in a log folder when that folder does not exist.

Comment: `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS" You cannot use characters / and : in file names.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps. Shall I create a new folder and store a sample log file in asset folder for it?

Comment: You can do what you want. I only told you two things you should NOT do. But you did not react on these suggestions.